# How to prove that the following inequality holds true?

Tags: statistics, inequality

To prove: $\frac{1}{2}(x_n-x_1)^2 < \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2 $.

I simplified the LHS to: $\frac{1}{2} (x_n^2-2x_1+x_1^2)$ and the RHS to $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i^2 -2\bar{x}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n{x_i} + n\bar{x}^2$, but this doesn't help as $x_1 \leq 2\bar{x}\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i$. Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $u_{i}:=x_{i}-\bar{x}$. Then it is to be shown that $\frac{1}{2}\left(u_{n}-u_{1}\right)^{2}\leq\sum_{i=1}^{n}u_{i}^{2}$
wich follows directly from $\frac{1}{2}\left(u_{n}-u_{1}\right)^{2}\leq u_{n}^{2}+u_{1}^{2}$
or equivalently $\left(u_{n}+u_{1}\right)^{2}\geq0$.

If $x_i=c$ for each $i$ then $<$ is simply not true here, but $\leq$ is.

Comment: Great, Thanks :)!